# Can we make an iOS app backward compatible

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

Can we make an iOS app backward compatible with older iOS versions?

As we can do in android apps using API Levels?

Comment: Till which IOS version bac you want to make app? Because Apple not accept less than IOS 8 version

Comment: There's a dropdown in the project settings where you can choose which OS version you want to support.

Comment: Starting from June 1st, 2015,APP updates needs to be 64bit and built with ios8 SDK.

Comment: I just want to support it back upto iOS 6 if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While building an iOS app, the architectures (armv7, armv7s, armv64) you choose dictate what all platforms you will be supporting. **The "Deployment target" version that you select in xcode is the minimum OS version that you can support.** An iOS app is a universal binary, which means that it can contain code supporting both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. Building with 64 bit support (iOS 8 SDK) is not the same as dropping support for earlier 32-bit OS versions.